# cmake crosscompile link boost

Tags: linux, boost, cmake, cross-compiling

I have a (YOCTO) SKD including boost for my ARM Target 32 Bit. Host in an Ubuntu 18.04.

How do I link Boost?

Comment: Setting `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` after the `project()` call is **wrong**. Instead, prepare separate toolchain file which sets toolchain-related CMake variables (`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`, `CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR`, `CMAKE_SYSROOT`, etc.) and use this file by passing option `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=/path/to/file` to `cmake` executable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by [@Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3440745/tsyvarev):

First prepare Toolchain, then make Project with linked Boost.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.19)

set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR armv7-a)

# sysroot
set(CMAKE_SYSROOT /opt/karo-base/1.0/sysroots/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH ${CMAKE_SYSROOT})

# compiler
set(TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX /opt/karo-base/1.0/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi/arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER ${TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX}g++)

set(COMPILER_FLAGS " -mthumb -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 -mfloat-abi=hard -mcpu=cortex-a7 -fstack-protector-strong -mbe32")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${COMPILER_FLAGS}" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE ONLY)

project(helloBoost )

# see https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindBoost.html
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS ALL)

add_executable(helloBoost main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(helloBoost Boost::boost Boost::log)
```